# Extracting channel statistics for multiple channel ids in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, youtube, data-analysis, data-mining

I have a dataframe of YouTube video statistics containing multiple channel ids (i.e. ids of channels with which each video is associated). Nearly 400 channel ids in the dataframe.
I am trying to extract the channel statistics through the following code

```
channel_stats <- get_channel_stats(channel_id = "UCCoIjOuBJ86zWAeoh0lp5Bw")
```

But the above code requires imputing of individual channel ids (as in code).

Is there any method to automate it? So that it can automatically scrape the channel statistics for each channel id in the dataframe.

```
structure(list(video_id = c("0TNgNxUovwc", "tAo-Yn2sENI", "4Y9tK-8aXZQ", "SFGtT4vBEQ4", "dkl_51r17BI", "aA8cOLkjJoc"), publishedAt = c("2021-02-14T05:40:53Z", "2021-02-16T20:02:47Z", "2020-12-30T15:07:06Z", "2021-02-02T23:15:01Z", "2021-03-21T23:30:17Z", "2021-03-16T01:35:56Z"), channelId = c("UCq0grzC77X9UZd9xngQRTjg", "UCew5br5cO1ZKO7Z_F1WA8Bg", "UCCoIjOuBJ86zWAeoh0lp5Bw", "UCxcTeAKWJca6XyJ37_ZoKIQ", "UCCoIjOuBJ86zWAeoh0lp5Bw", "UCWKhaRyXJSvt4m2sizsSNsA")))
```

Comment: Provide us with some example data e.g. using `dput(head(df)` where df is the data frame having column channel_id

Comment: structure(list(video_id = c("0TNgNxUovwc", "tAo-Yn2sENI", "4Y9tK-8aXZQ", 
"SFGtT4vBEQ4", "dkl_51r17BI", "aA8cOLkjJoc"), publishedAt = c("2021-02-14T05:40:53Z", 
"2021-02-16T20:02:47Z", "2020-12-30T15:07:06Z", "2021-02-02T23:15:01Z", 
"2021-03-21T23:30:17Z", "2021-03-16T01:35:56Z"), channelId = c("UCq0grzC77X9UZd9xngQRTjg", 
"UCew5br5cO1ZKO7Z_F1WA8Bg", "UCCoIjOuBJ86zWAeoh0lp5Bw", "UCxcTeAKWJca6XyJ37_ZoKIQ", 
"UCCoIjOuBJ86zWAeoh0lp5Bw", "UCWKhaRyXJSvt4m2sizsSNsA")

Comment: In which channel statistics are you interested? What is `get_channel_stats` doing?

Comment: I require statistics of all channels in the dataframe but the function only enables insertion of individual channel ids. I can input each channel id to extract the specific channel statistics but I need help to automate the process so that each channel_id is extracted one  by one. Please refer to [link] https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tuber/versions/0.9.9/topics/get_channel_stats

Comment: @danloo output of `get_channel_stats(UCq0grzC77X9UZd9xngQRTjg)`                                                                                             Channel Title: Highlight Heaven 
No. of Views: 1425311078 
No. of Subscribers: 1220000 
No. of Videos: 3449